# Lambda, How to use Contains?

Tags: asp.net, json, lambda

I want to retrieve data using Lambda,

If writing Query the,

```
SELECT * FROM weborderln WHERE PK in ('60fa6105-42c9-aa4b-82a2-1d84f803a540','adsfasfwer-we123-1231b-82a2-12312312sd5125');
```

the PK values from Jason Data.

```
string itemsInfo = "[{\"itemNo\":\"SKR315FLWW\",\"qty\":1,\"weborderlnPk\":\"60fa6105-42c9-aa4b-82a2-1d84f803a540\"},{\"itemNo\":\"OKHIY211\",\"qty\":1,\"weborderlnPk\":\"adsfasfwer-we123-1231b-82a2-12312312sd5125\"}]"; 

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
IList<PartialInvoiceParamsModel> items = js.Deserialize<IList<PartialInvoiceParamsModel>>(itemsInfo);

//Response.Write(items[0].itemNo); // SKR315FLWW

EFWebOrderLnRepository webOrderLnRepository = new EFWebOrderLnRepository();
var webOrderLns = webOrderLnRepository.WebOrderLns.Where(e => e.PK.Contains(?????)).ToList(); ////
```

Anybody know what I need to put into the Contains()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have list of IDs:

```
List<string> listIDs = new List<string> { "60fa6105-42c9-aa4b-82a2-1d84f803a540", 
                                          "60fa6105-42c9-aa4b-82a2-1d84f803a541", 
                                          "60fa6105-42c9-aa4b-82a2-1d84f803a542" 
                                         };
var webOrderLns = from foo in webOrderLnRepository.WebOrderLns 
                  where listIDs.Contains(foo.PK) 
                  select foo;
```

This will give you records where the ID matches from the list IDs

Answer (score 1):

It seems a litte backward at first, but you need to do the contains on the list of items you are checking.

So you need to create a list of PK's to do the contains on.
For example:

```
var webOrderLns = webOrderLnRepository.WebOrderLns.Where(e => items.Select(x => x.weborderlnPk).Contains(e.PK)).ToList();
```

The `items.Select(x => x.weborderlnPk)` should create the list of PK's for you to do the contains with.